# Entity framework core groupBy and distinct

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this query

```
items = await context.Bookings
                        .GroupBy(p => p.Start.Day, p => p.BookedById, (key, g) => new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(key, g.Distinct().Count()))
                        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

it gives me error:
Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([p].Start.Day, [p].BookedById)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

but if I change it to double group by like this

```
items = await context.Bookings
                    .GroupBy(p => new { p.Start.Day, p.BookedById })
                    .Select(c => new { c.Key.Day, c.Key.BookedById, Count = c.Count() })
                    .GroupBy(z => z.Day)
                    .Select(c => new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(c.Key, c.Count()))
                    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

it works
is there any way not to use double group only distinct ?

In others words what I want is unique useres list count booked in day

```
lets have this sample of data: day, user, bookingsCount {(1, ad, 2), (1, ac, 3), (2, be, 1), (2, be 3)} so the result should be dayNumber, usersCount: (1,2) , (2, 1)
```

and where Bookings class has at least Start, BookedById and End columns
in my second query count in this line is not necessery  `.Select(c => new { c.Key.Day, c.Key.BookedById, Count = c.Count() })`

Comment: I think you should be happy with the workaround you've found. EF Core query translation is still, let say, far from perfect. The first query should ideally translate to `COUNT(DISTINCT column)` SQL construct, but it doesn't. May be some day (EF Core 3.0+)

Comment: GroupBy() SQL translations have only just been added to EF core 2.1. What version are you using?

Comment: @reckface I can confirm it's happening with the latest at this time EF Core 2.2

Comment: Unfortunately it is still happening with EF Core 3.